# Proper way to have shared resources across platforms in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have a .NET standard platform project and two target projects in the same solution, one for each target platform (iOS and Android). The problem is that currently I have to maintain in parallel two sets of duplicated raw assets (.ttf and .db3 files), so I was wondering whether there is a way to have only one set of assets shared across all the target platforms.

Comment: given that the build actions are different for embedded assets/resources such as fonts and images are BundleResource and AndroidAsset, that would be neat trick.

Comment: @philsoady I tried adding the asset files as links, and it did the trick. I can have one folder with assets now, but two folders in VS, each folder in a different target project, pointing to the same raw files.